# For me Autocompletion is not working jupyter notebook and the kernel is getting crashed frequently

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

It was fine like 1 week back but when I opened Jupyter notebook and started coding but autocompletion is not working, then I uninstalled it even Anaconda and reinstalled it still not working properly(i know about shift-tab but I unless press it is coming, starting it is used to come when I simply start typing the code). And the major problem is kernel is getting crashed frequently like cells are not running sometimes if I press shift-enter rather than executing it is moving to the next cell, even if I restart the kernel after running a certain no of cells it is stopping.

I even tried

```
pip uninstall Jedi --yes
```

(please do guide me it is literally a pain in the neck to type everything)
Thanks in advance

Comment: For those issues, you want to go to a help forum (https://discourse.jupyter.org/) or open a bug report, stackoverflow will not be useful with a kind of debugging that needs back and forth. If you have error messages of warnings messages you will need to post them.

Comment: No, what i thought is people might have faced a similar issue so I just asked to confirm

Comment: When you update a package Jedi can sometime be REEEEAAAAALY slow on the first completions. But this is weird. Try opening the JS console as well in your browser to see if there are any error messages. It may be a browser extension interfering. Does tab completion works from terminal IPython is also a good indicator.

Comment: So your saying to disable my extensions

Comment: That, in case it has an effect, or tryanohter browser temporarily.